# Right head light in 98 honda accord fuses out regularly

Tags: honda, headlight, accord

I have changed the headlights on the 98 Honda accord 3 times already and the right one constantly fuses out.

How do I start diagnosing the issue?

Comment: This should be posted to the main site.

Comment: When you say, "fuses out" ... would that mean the same thing as "burns out"? Or are you saying the fuse going to the headlight is burning out?

Comment: Well, I just used the word to mean that it has stopped working. btw, I replaced them today, and will comment on how long they last.

Comment: If my research is right, your bulb is a 9005 halogen bulb. When you replace these, it is ***IMPERATIVE*** that you do not touch the bulb with your bare fingers (the glass part) as this will *dramatically* reduce the bulb's longevity. I'm saying if you touch it, you can expect the bulb to last about two to three weeks, tops. It absolutely kills these bulbs.

Comment: @Paulster2, thanks - it is a 9006 halogen bulb. I will update on how long it lasts.

Comment: @Paulster2 : Please post up your comment as an answer so we can move this question out of the "Unanswered" category

Answer (score 1):

If my research is right, your bulb is a 9005 halogen bulb. When you replace these, it is IMPERATIVE that you do not touch the bulb with your bare fingers (the glass part) as this will dramatically reduce the bulb's longevity. I'm saying if you touch it, you can expect the bulb to last about two to three weeks, tops. It absolutely kills these bulbs.